# Using a triac to switch on/off a single phase AC motor

Tags: motor, ac, triac

I want to use a triac controlled by a suitable optoisolator such as a MOC3020 to switch a single phase AC motor on and off, like the ones you'd find in a typical desk fan or a blender or similar.

I don't want speed control... just on or off.

I've used triacs in the past to switch resistive loads, which have worked with no problems.

Is there anything special or different I need to do to switch an inductive load? Do I need to include any kind of protection or noise suppression? If so what additional components are needed, and how are they implemented?

Comment: This issue has been dealt with before [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14296/why-snub-an-optoisolator). Pages 6 & 7 of the [fairchild datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MO/MOC3010M.pdf) refer to inductive loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [3-quadrant triac](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN_3Q_TRIACS.pdf) is well-suited for inductive loads like a motor. It is resistant to spurious turn-on caused by sudden \$\frac{dv}{dt}\$ - like the inductive kick from a motor.